# Workflow - Custom Form submitted

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have created a very simple Workflow that contains two activities:
1- FormSubmitted (starts the Workflow, I specify a certain form)
2- Notify (to display a customized message on screen)

Now, when I hit "Submit" on the form, the browser hangs on and keeps on loading and loading, as if the operation is taking time. Nothing then happens,

Any idea?

Comment: If you have such a clear repro that works on a vanilla Orchard install, please file a bug.

Comment: For some reason, I tried the cycle again on a new Content Type and it worked fine. I already filed that on CodePlex. Thanks